# Node.js Firebase Token

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm using node.js and Mysql local database, I want to get a firebase token at the moment of registration and save it with the other attributes of the user. There is an npm module for example ?!

```js
app.post('/CreateUser/:nounpronoun/:status/:mail/:password',function(req,res){
connection.query("INSERT INTO user (Noun_Pronoun, Status, Mail, Password) VALUES ('"+req.params.nounpronoun+"', '"+req.params.status+"', '"+req.params.mail+"', '"+req.params.password+"')", function(error,rows, fields){
if(!!error){console.log('Error in the query');
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ code: 0 }));}
  else {console.log('successful inesrtion');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ code: 1 }));}
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate a token and save it when you need it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-token-generator

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(
    {uid: "1", some: "arbitrary", data: "here"},
    {admin: true}
);
```

Here's the github source as well: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node

Comment: The token normally is a unique string no ?! here it's a json

Comment: You can send it as a string, but a JSON allows you to contain a lot more useful info ;)